# Why an object is created if I try to print a class's non-static member function's address in c++?

Tags: c++, class, g++, cout

I found one interesting behavior while I was just checking non-static member variable's offsets

It looks like if I try to print non-static member function's address in pointer
It just creates a new object for the class which has the member function

Is this a normal behavior or undefined behavior that I can just ignore?

for instance if I try below code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef void(*FP)();

class AAA {
public:
    int var1;
    int var2;

    void foo() {
        std::cout << &var1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << &var2 << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    FP fp = reinterpret_cast<FP>(&AAA::foo);
    std::cout << fp << std::endl;
    fp();
}
```

Its result is like below

```sh
$ ./a.out
0x56001ea8d940
0x7fe36c93c760
0x7fe36c93c764
```

So I removed `cout` statement then it just prints member's offset like I expected

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef void(*FP)();

class AAA {
public:
    int var1;
    int var2;

    void foo() {
        std::cout << &var1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << &var2 << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    FP fp = reinterpret_cast<FP>(&AAA::foo);
    fp();
}
```

and its result is like below

```sh
$ g++ main.cpp (with some warnings anyway)
$ ./a.out
0x1
0x5
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. You can't call a non-static member function without an object.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not magic that can do anything, it is rather the opposite, it has a quite limited list of cases where it can be used, this is for sure none of them

Comment: If, for some reason, you want the offset of a non-static member variable, use the [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) macro.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you for your quick answer! one more question here, I didn't call a non-static member function and just tried to print the value in pointer, and do you mean cout internally call the function? or getting nont-static memeber function's address is already UB?

Comment: What do you think that `fp()` does?

Comment: Aha Ok, it doesn't matter whether fp() is before cout or after cout and even cout is not a significant factor because it gets UB already, thank you so much

Comment: A pointer-to-member-function is not a pointer-to-function. It usually some extra stuff so that you can apply it to objects of different derived types. Pretending that it is one (i.e., casting it) only leads to trouble.

Answer (score 3):

The weird behaviour you’re seeing is undefined behaviour caused by the following line:

```
FP fp = reinterpret_cast<FP>(&AAA::foo);
```

*Even without calling `fp`* this is already undefined behaviour! [Only the listed conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) are valid for `reinterpret_cast` ([[expr.reinterpret.cast]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast)), and the one you’re using (member function pointer to function pointer) is not one of them.

It’s a common misunderstanding that `reinterpret_cast` is an “anything goes” cast that allows circumventing type safety in any way imaginable. According to the standard, that’s not the case; only a handful of specific conversions are valid. All others are not (but do not require diagnosis, which leads to them being used anyway).